# SQL theory: Filtering out duplicates in one column, picking lowest value in other column

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to figure out the best way to remove rows from a result set where either the value in one column or the value in a different column has a duplicate in the result set.

Imagine the results of a query are as follows:

```
a_value | b_value
-----------------
   1    |   1
   2    |   1
   2    |   2
   3    |   1
   4    |   3
   5    |   2
   6    |   4
   6    |   5
```

What I want to do is:

- Eliminate all rows that have duplicate values in a_value
- Pick only 1 row for a given b_value

So I'd want the filtered results to end up like this after eliminating a_value duplicates:

```
a_value | b_value
-----------------
   1    |   1
   3    |   1
   4    |   3
   5    |   2
```

And then like this after picking only a single b_value:

```
a_value | b_value
-----------------
   1    |   1
   4    |   3
   5    |   2
```

I'd appreciate suggestions on how to accomplish this task in an efficient way via SQL.

Comment: Any restrictions, such as no temp tables? Also, sql server, mysql, oracle, or ?

Comment: Do you have some id column in your data? If yes - and if using mysql, you could use a left join. At least for the first filtered result

Comment: For my use case, it is Oracle. Temp tables would be fine if it is more efficient for large sets of data coming from 2 tables.

Comment: I'm interested in understanding both how, but also why.

Comment: On the second pass, why is 1,1 picked over 3,1  pair ? Is the lower A value preferred ?

Comment: It was arbitrary. I just care that one of them was picked. But good question :)

Comment: Is the logic on second pass the same as first pass ? If yes, shouldn't the output be (4,3),(5,2) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with
     q_res ( a_value, b_value ) as (
       select 1, 1 from dual union all
       select 2, 1 from dual union all
       select 2, 2 from dual union all
       select 3, 1 from dual union all
       select 4, 3 from dual union all
       select 5, 2 from dual union all
       select 6, 4 from dual union all
       select 6, 5 from dual
     )
-- end test data; solution begins below
select   min(a_value) as a_value, b_value
from     ( 
           select   a_value, min(b_value) as b_value
           from     q_res
           group by a_value
           having   count(*) = 1
         )
group by b_value
order by a_value   -- ORDER BY is optional
;

A_VALUE  B_VALUE
-------  -------
      1        1
      4        3
      5        2
```

Answer (score 1):

1) In the inner query I am avoiding all duplicates which are present in a_value 
   column and getting all the remaining rows from input table and storing them
   as t2. By joining t2 with t1 there would be full data without any dups as per 
   your #1 in requirement.

```
 SELECT t1.*
   FROM Table t1,
      (
        SELECT a_value       
          FROM Table 
         GROUP BY a_value
         HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
       ) t2
   WHERE t1.a_value = t2.a_value;
```

2) Once the filtered data is obtained, I am assigning rank to each row in the filtered dataset obtained in step-1 and I am selecting only rows with rank=1.

```
SELECT X.a_value,
       X.b_value
  FROM
     (
        SELECT t1.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t1.b_value ORDER BY t1.a_value,t1.b_value ) AS rn 
          FROM Table t1,
             (
               SELECT a_value       
                 FROM Table 
                GROUP BY a_value
               HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
              ) t2
         WHERE t1.a_value = t2.a_value 
       ) X
WHERE X.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Is this really the best way to do it? Just wrap the results in other selects that apply the filtering via grouping or window functions?

Comment: Does the above answer your question?

Comment: It assumes a 1-1 join between both tables, which isn't the case, but it does answer the basics on how to do it. I was hoping there was a better way than just wrapping my select query with 2 other layers of select queries (effectively).